# Not able to write output of python script to text file in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a python script to extract the tweets from twitter. I want to write the output into a text file.

When I run the .py file from Anaconda command prompt, it shows me the output in the command prompt. But when I try to write the same output to a file, it doesn't write anything.

```
C:\Users\akjain>python c:\Akash\TweetExtract.py >> twitter_data.txt
```

I have tried to open the Ananconda as an Administrator too.  Also created the text file in the same folder where I have python script before running the script.
I also tried the below code but this also did not work.

```
C:\windows\system32>python c:\Akash\GartnerTweetExtract.py > c:\Akash\twitter_data.txt
```

**Edit:**

Code to print the ouput to command prompt which is inside my python script is as follows:

```
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Comment: Can you please show the snippet of your code that does the file operation?

Comment: Hi Mohit,
I have the code to print the fetched tweet in cmd..                                    
 class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

Comment: Add it to your question. It's easier for everyone that way.

Comment: Following this blog. the statement is just above the point no 2 in the blog. http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

Comment: There are no file operations in your code.

Comment: This is just a class definition, there is nothing which actually calls it. Are you sure it prints something if you run it without the redirect?

Comment: I am putting same code as mentioned in Step 2: Connecting to Twitter Streaming API and downloading data in the above blog with just my API tokens. And yes prints the output in cmd when I don't output in the file.

Comment: Do you need a code script to do file operations? I didn't write any explicit script but sill anoconda is able to write the output to a text file like a charm.

Comment: @shahidammer : I think it doesnt need the code script to do the file operations. It should ideally write the output from anaconda command prompt only. But somehow it is not writing for me. I can very clearly see new tweets in the command prompt. Something to do with file permission ? Or any other setting needed to write to file.

Comment: @Ashish : I tried this also but it is still not writing. So looks like nothing to do with code. Something to do with file permission. May be. But I am admin for my laptop.

Comment: @shahidammer : It worked fine without code script to do file operations. I placed the file in c:\users\akjain and it is writing it to file. Thanks

Comment: Great! I would like if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: I actually wanted to accept the answer. But somehow your answer was not visible the moment I accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my best guess is that you are facing permission issues. Why don't you copy the file to ***C:\Users\akjain>*** and run

```
python TweetExtract.py > your-file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your output in text file using following code snippet, this way you can also check what error it's throwing in case of failure.

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        with open('twitter_data.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
```

Comment: tried this and it worked fine. Actually there was 2-3 mins delay in writing it to file . So I was thinking its not writing at all. Surprised to see it fetches the twitter data so slow.. Thank you for your help.